# In which secret, magical directory does a VS unit test execute?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nunit

So, my first VS(2012)/NUnit unit test experience...

The unit test project is referencing assembly A (the code which needs to be tested), which requires assembly B.  So, I have also referenced assembly B.  Both files are copied to the output directory.

However, when I run the test, it fails because it cannot load assembly B.  Odd, it must be running the test from another directory.

So, I open up Resharper, disable shadow copy.  Still fails.

Double and triple check all necessary files are referenced and in the output directory.  They are.

Start to do some research, find [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which implies that I can disable deployment and just run the test from my output directory.  However, my unit test project has no "run configuration file" that I can find, but it is required in step one of the walk through.  Drat.

I then stumble across the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) attribute.  I add this to my test method and, lo and behold, it works.  However, I'd rather not pepper every test method with this attribute forevermore, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Does anyone know how to just tell the darned test framework to copy all of the files in my output directory *or* to just run the thing from that directory to begin with?  This seems like it should be simple and default instead of magical and hidden... thanks in advance.

I'm gonna go ahead and vent. This is one of the most brain dead design decisions I have ever encountered.  They have the project file, they know which assemblies/files are referenced, they know if they are set to "Copy Always"... yet they ignore all of that.

The default behavior is to run only the most trivial of "Hello World" projects and break everything else, wasting my/your time.  What are these developers thinking?  ...Feel better now.

Comment: Yes, quite an annoying trek. I actually logged `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to find out.

Comment: @IAbstract: Yeah, I guess the title is a bit misleading at this point.  I did find out where it is running from... but that's irrelevant; I need the damn thing to just copy the correct files over. I don't understand why the default behavior would be to break your program...

Comment: The CLR *never* uses the current working directory to find assemblies so it just doesn't matter what it is set at.  I can't for the life of me figure out what test runner you are actually using.  Is it VS, NUnit or Resharper?

Comment: @HansPassant: It certainly matters.  The thing works fine as long as the correct DLL's are copied in.  Same goes for resource files.  This is an NUnit project.

Comment: Added a test config file, added the files to copy over... still doesn't copy them over.

Comment: If you know the path you need the items copied to, you could add a post build event to copy the files to the path.

Comment: Do you have the "Copy Local" property set for your referenced assemblies?

Comment: @JakeHeidt: Right, I'm not saying it's impossible.  I said in the question that the DeploymentItem attribute works, it's just clunk and unnecessary

Comment: A .runsettings file is just a renamed XML file (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) however it won't help as the DeploymentEnabled flag is just for MSTest tests.  I'm also a little unclear - are you using Test Explorer to run the tests or R#? The reference to R# and shadow copy is muddying the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy additional files into test folder, and don't want to use DeploymentItemAttribute - you can create and add to your solution a .testsettings file. There you can configure your additional files / directories for deployment, setup and cleanup scripts, etc. See MSDN description of [**test settings files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx).